# ReactJS how to map an array based on the order of another array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

The answer in Unmitigated helped me, if you are searching from google scroll down

order:
`[ "567", "645", "852", "645", "852", "852", ]`

database:
`[ { "userId": 567, "userName": "tjk23", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "" }, { "userId": 645, "userName": "gfn23", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "" }, { "userId": 852, "userName": "dan24", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "", } ]`

Currently it's mapping fine with the database array, but only displays 3 of the DisplayCard. I need it to display 6 times and also in the order of the 6 in order array

`{database.map((data, index) => { return <DisplayCard data={data} key={index}/>                   })}`

How do I make it map using the sequence of the order array without changing too much code? As the DisplayCard is used in multiple places I would like to not modify it

I tried using

`{order.map((database.data, index) => { return <DisplayCard data={database.data} key={index}/>                   })}`

and expected it to use the sequence of the order array, and get the data from the corresponding userId in the database array

But what actually resulted is an error but I don't know why

Edit for Unmitigated:
Here is a minimally reproducible example, I removed the API call and external DisplayCard reference and have everything fit into this snippet

```
export function Minimal() {
    var lookup;

    const order= [ "567", "645", "852", "645", "852", "852", ];

    const database = [ { "userId": 567, "userName": "tjk23", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "" }, { "userId": 645, "userName": "gfn23", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "" }, { "userId": 852, "userName": "dan24", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "", } ];
    
    function DisplayCard({data}) {
        return <div>{data.userId}</div>;
      }

    return (<>

    {database?.length > 0
        ? lookup = Object.fromEntries(database.map(o => [o.userId, o]))
        (
            <>
                {order.map((userId, index) => {
                    return <DisplayCard data={lookup[userId]} key={index} />                  
                })}     
            </>
        ) :
        (
            <div className="empty">
                <h2>No records found</h2>
            </div>
        )}
    
</>)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object that maps each `userId` to an object in the array, then access the values from this lookup object when using `order`.

```
let lookup = Object.fromEntries(database.map(o => [o.userId, o]));
// ...
{order.map((id, index) => <DisplayCard data={lookup[id]} key={index}/>)}
```

Example:

```js
function DisplayCard({data}) {
  return <div>{data.userName}</div>;
}

function App() {
  let order = [ "567", "645", "852", "645", "852", "852", ];
  let [database, setDatabase] = React.useState([ { "userId": 567, "userName": "tjk23", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "" }, { "userId": 645, "userName": "gfn23", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "" }, { "userId": 852, "userName": "dan24", "department": "Sales", "remarks": "", } ]);
  let lookup = Object.fromEntries(database.map(o => [o.userId, o]));
  return (
    <div>
      {order.map((id, index) => <DisplayCard data={lookup[id]} key={index}/>)}
      <button onClick={() => setDatabase([{userId: 567, userName: 'changed 567'}, {userId: 645, userName: 'changed 645'}, {userId: 852, userName: 'changed 852'}])}>Change state</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: DisplayCard.jsx:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userName')

I'm still trying to see what went wrong but this is the error I got when I immediately pasted your code

Comment: @wynnawinner Do you have ids that don't exist in `order`?

Comment: @wynnawinner I've updated my answer with a snippet that shows the code working. There is probably an issue elsewhere in your code.

Comment: No, the database array is derived from the order array through axios, that should not be possible

Comment: @wynnawinner You can see that the code works in the snippet given the information provided in the question. If it doesn't work on your end, then please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I just defined everything locally and made a minimal reproducible example in the question edit

Comment: @wynnawinner The issue is that you defined `lookup` in the wrong location. You need to declare it as a separate variable. Putting it right under the definition of `database` as `const lookup = Object.fromEntries(database.map(o => [o.userId, o]));` would work.

Comment: You mean just moving the var lookup line after the const database line right? It errors Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '567') Minimal.js

Comment: @wynnawinner No, I mean completely removing `var lookup` and instead having `const lookup = Object.fromEntries(database.map(o => [o.userId, o]));` after the `database` definition. Do NOT add `lookup = Object.fromEntries(database.map(o => [o.userId, o]))` inside the JSX. (Currently, you have it after `database?.length > 0 ?`, which is not correct and should be deleted.) See how `lookup` is defined and used in the example snippet of my answer.

Comment: It works that way but I need lookup to be changed every time the database array changes

Comment: @wynnawinner How does defining `lookup` after `database` not accomplish that? Just define it inside the component, not inside the JSX and it will change on each render if `database` changes.

Comment: Because database is a useState and will change without a page reload that will trigger the lookup code if I put in the the location you told me to. That's why I thought to put in the jsx fragment so when database array refreshes var lookup gets assigned again

Comment: @wynnawinner When you set the state, the component is rerendered, so the code inside runs again. Thus it is correct to define `lookup` inside the component.

Comment: @wynnawinner I've updated the example snippet in my answer to show it working with state.

Comment: Ohhh I'm so sorry I thought that the lookup const can't change in that position and only code in jsx {database?.length... } will rerender and reexecute due to useState database?.length state change and not the whole Minimal(). That's why I thought to put it there. Thank you!!!

Comment: "Do you have ids that don't exist in order?"

Comment: when order update, it takes a while for the fetch request to come back, so in that time when it lookup using the ids array, it will crash my react app because the lookup will update faster than the fetch request coming back

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  order.map((id, index) => {
    const target = datebase.find(item => item.userId === id)
    return target ? <DisplayCard data={target} key={index} /> : null
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems to always return the null portion. (It didn't return anything at first, but I replaced null with "test" and all it displayed "test")

Comment: Maybe you should replace '===' with '=='?

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is not map, it's a filtering on database array. The map method is not used like you are thinking see definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

I strongly believe that this is a way without changing too much code

Step 1: Filter **database** array according to the ids on **order** array

Step 2: Now you can use the **database** array filtered

```
let resultsFiltered = database.filter(item => order.includes(item.userId))
    
{resultsFiltered.map((data, index) => { return <DisplayCard data={data} key={index}/>})}
```